# Book on stability theory

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a book on stability theory. More precisely, I am interested in the case of a system of differential equations $\frac{dx}{dt}=Ax + F(x),$ where $A$ is a constant matrix, such that two of its eigenvalues have zero real parts and other eigenvalues have negative real parts. Where can I read Lyapunov's results on when the zero solution is stable?

Answer (score 2):

There is a detailed discussion of these problems in "Geometrical methods in the theory of ODE" by V.I.Arnold, though I think this is much more general than what you're looking for.

So I recommend two other books of the same author, "Ordinary differential equations" and "Advanced chapters in theory of ODE".